# Having trouble sending file through HTTP (through TCP) in python. What is the issue with my code?

Tags: python, tcp, http-headers, httpresponse, file-transfer

I have created a server in python, and am trying to send a file over to a client when the file is requested. The server receives the request, but then I cannot send the file over through TCP.

I used a template to create a response header, and then I try to send the file afterward, but it does not entirely work. I am able to "send" .py and .html files over, and they do display in my browser, but it must be luck, because according to my TA, the real test is images... which are not working for me.

First I will post the header and response as shown by the Firefox addon Firebug, then my code, and lastly the error message.

**Firebug Request and Response**

**----------------------------**

**Response Headersview source**

```
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Connection  Keep-Alive (or Connection: close)Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length  10000
Keep-Alive  timeout=10, max=100
```

**Request Headersview source**

```
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Host    xxx.xxx.244.5:10000
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0
```

** My python code: **

```
#import socket module
from socket import *
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
#Prepare a server socket
serverPort = 10000
serverName = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xx' #Laptop IP
serverSocket.bind((serverName,serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(5)

while True:
    #Establish the connection
    print 'Ready to serve...'
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
    print addr

    try:
        message = connectionSocket.recv(4096)
        filename = message.split()[1]
        f = open(filename[1:])
        outputdata = f.read()
        f.close()
        print 'length of output data: '
        print len(outputdata)
        print filename
        print message
        header = ("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
        "Accept-Ranges: bytes\r\n"
        "Content-Length: 100000\r\n"
        "Keep-Alive: timeout=10, max=100\r\n"
        "Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n (or Connection: close)"
        "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n"
        "\r\n")
        connectionSocket.send(header)
        #Send the content of the requested file to the client
        for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):
                connectionSocket.sendall(outputdata[i])         
        connectionSocket.close()


        print '\ntry code has executed\n'

    except IOError:
        print 'exception code has been executed'
        connectionSocket.send('HTTP/1.1 404 Not found: The requested document does not exist on this server.')
        connectionSocket.send('If you can read this, then the exception code has run')
        print '\tconnectionSocket.send has executed'
        connectionSocket.close()
        print '\tconnectionSocket.close has executed\n'
#serverSocket.close()
```

**And here is the error message:**

This image "http://xxx.xxx.244.5:10000/kitty.jpg" cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

**Thank you in advance!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your JPEG file in binary mode: `open(filename[1:], "rb")`. Otherwise Python will helpfully translate some bytes in the file to `\n` characters, which will corrupt the image and prevent the browser from being able to make any sense of it.

Also, you should use a `Content-Type` of `image/jpeg` for a JPEG image, rather than `text/html`, although your browser seems to have figured out that it's a JPEG anyway.

Comment: WOWOWOWOW!!!! That worked. I have spent two days trying to figure this one out! The template code (that was provided for us to modify wrote that line as I pasted it. Thank you so much! I will read up on python's file handling now... I guess I didn't have the experience to question the template. I am having other problems with the script (server crashing if I cancel the file trasnfer from the client side, but I will attempt to figure that out later today.) You have solved my biggest problem!